# why does my plotly image not show properly on dash app

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I am wanting to have an app that returns the click data when the user clicks on an image. Outside the app, the image shows properly, but when I make it into an app, I cannot see the image. I have tried turning the image into base64, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Here's the function that takes a local image and returns the associated plotly plot (appropriately shows the image):

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import base64
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

def make_img(source):
    with open(source, "rb") as image_file:
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode()
        #add the prefix that plotly will want when using the string as source
    encoded_image = "data:image/png;base64," + encoded_string

    x = np.linspace(0.1, 2.8, 100)
    y = np.linspace(0, 3, 100)
    df = pd.DataFrame(product(x, y), columns=['x', 'y'])

    fig = px.scatter(x=df['x'], y=df['y'])

    img_width = 3
    img_height = 3
    scale_factor = 1
    fig.add_layout_image(
            x=0,
            sizex=img_width,
            y=0,
            sizey=img_height,
            xref="x",
            yref="y",
            opacity=1,
            layer="above",
            source=source,
    )

    fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False, 
                     showline=False, 
                     visible=False,
                     zeroline=False,
                     range=(0, img_width)),

    fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=False, 
                     showline=False, 
                     visible=False,
                     zeroline=False,
                     scaleanchor='x', 
                     range=(img_height, 0))

    # No hover text

    hover_name = ""
    fig.update_traces(
       hovertext="", 
        hovertemplate=f'<b>{hover_name}<b>'
    )
    return fig
```

Here's the app (image does not show):

```
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children = [dcc.Graph(
    figure=make_img('img.png'),
    style={'height': 600},
    id='my-graph'
)])

app.css.append_css({
    'external_url': 'https://codepen.io/illsci/pen/wxZMQm.css'
})


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('click-data', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('basic-interactions', 'clickData')])

def display_click_data(clickData):
    return json.dumps(clickData, indent=2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(threaded = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just realized I was using source=source instead of source=encoded_image. Works now :)